# What is a word that means an inability or refusal to accept losing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need the word or word combination that describes a person who is unable to accept losing.

Comment: Sore loser perhaps.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase **must include information on how it will be used** in order to be answered.

Comment: Caralite, how has this person shown an inability to accept losing?  Tell us more so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

A **"bad sport"** comes to mind.

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poor/bad%20sport) defines a "bad sport" as a person who is rude or angry about losing.

Answer (score 0):

"Never say die" fits.
If you have a never-say-die attitude, you don't give up or get discouraged, no matter what. People love a never-say-die spirit because it describes people or teams that just don't quit. Unless they die, then they can't say it anymore.
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/never-say-die